# Redimensionar imagem com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Teria como construir com JavaScript uma interface de manipulação de imagens parecida com a do Word, que tem a opção de aumentar a imagem ou diminuir com o mouse?

Comment: Redimensionar para um tamanho fixo no código, ou sendo o próprio utilizador da página a redimensionar estilo Word?

Comment: sendo o próprio utilizador da página a redimensionar estilo Word

Comment: O próprio [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) tem funcionalidade para isso com `$("#omeuimg").resizable();`

Comment: cara não deu certo

Comment: Para funcionar tem de incluir a biblioteca de [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) caso ainda não o esteja a fazer, como indica nos [exemplos](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/), que é diferente de Jquery normal só

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É muito trabalhoso fazer isso manualmente. Existe uma propriedade CSS que resolve isso, mas só permite puxar pra aumentar a imagem pelo canto inferior direito, e ainda tem [suporte limitado](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize). Mas é interessante:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/codecode.jpg?w=738">
</div>
<p>Puxe o canto inferior direito da imagem</p>
```

Pra garantir suporte completo e mais funcionalidades, só [construindo na mão](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/) ou [usando uma biblioteca](http://interactjs.io/).